# What is the difference between angular.module("app",[]) and angular.module("app")

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the ng-book it is specified that `angular.module("app",[])` method is called the `setter` method for the Angular module and `angular.module("app")` method is known as the `getter` method, whereby we can get the Angular module for
later reference. What I understand is that the earlier is used for some dependency injection and for later module I do not have any idea. And in the second module definition it is said that we can get the Angular module for later reference, what is it meant?

Comment: the words "setter" and "getter", do they mean nothing to you?

Comment: I don't get why this question even gets onto SO since this is really well explained in the [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)....

Comment: @skubski: who needs docs, right?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, I do have good idea about these in the programming languages Java or C# but what it is referring in angularJS?

Comment: @JSNinja: same stuff. One _sets_ a value, the other one _gets_ it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `angular.module("app",[])` you are actually defining a module.

```
(function(){
 // define sub modules
 var subModule1 = angular.module('SubModule1',[]);
 var subModule2 = angular.module('SubModule2',[]);
 // define main module and import/register sub modules with main module sub modules
 var main = angular.module('MainModule',['subModule1', 'subModule2']);
}());
```

With `angular.module("MainModule")` you are getting a reference to MainModule, and then you can create new controller & service in that module.

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('App');
  app.controller('SkillController', function($scope, SkillService) {
    $scope.skills = ['Java', 'JavaScript'];
    $scope.skillName;
    $scope.addSkill = function() {
      SkillService.addSkill($scope.skills, $scope.skillName);
      $scope.skillName = '';
    };
    $scope.removeSkill = function(skillIndex) {
      console.log(' skillIndex : ' + skillIndex);
      SkillService.removeSkill($scope.skills, skillIndex);
    };
  });
 }());
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BGcuxM?p=info

Answer (score 1):

> angular.module('', []);

Will create a new module of the name specified, where the array is the set of dependent modules you want to make available within your new module. This will also return the newly created module.

> angular.module('');

Will retrieve the instance of the module via the name you defined when you created it.

**NOTE:** You should only be creating the module once as you do not want to overwrite what you've already created.

Answer (score 1):

Using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the module `myModule` and overwrite any existing module named `myModule`. This array is the list of modules app depends on.

Use `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module.